# Safely Charging a 5V Power Bank with a 6V Solar Panel

Tags: power, battery-charging, solar-cell

I am essentially trying to mimick the Voltaic power banks that are designed to be used with 6V solar panels, but cannot seem to find decent spec sheets on most other brands of power banks like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LRK8JDC) from amazon. I would love to use Voltaic's, however they are too large for my use case.

What are industry standards for max DC input into the power bank? Is 6V safe? Or should I design a quick drop-out circuit to regulate to 5V input into a normal power bank?

Comment: Unless there's a regulator somewhere, the odds that a "6V" solar panel will actually be producing 6V are pretty slim.

Comment: How about testing one and "acquiring" your own spec?